# tikz-knots: unexpected(?) behaviour with a circle

Tags: tikz-knots

Here's my knot:

[image]

I started by drawing the red+blue strand, which went quite well with a Hobby curve.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots, hobby, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  knot diagram/every strand/.append style={
    ultra thick,
    red
  }}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
 \begin{knot}[scale=2,
   consider self intersections=true,%ignore endpoint
   % intersections=false,
   end tolerance=0.05mm,
  draft mode=crossings,
   flip crossing/.list={1,3},
   clip width=8,
   clip radius=8pt,
   only when rendering/.style={
   }
   ]
 \strand ([closed]2,0) .. (3, 0) .. (4, 2) .. (1.5, 0) .. (1.8, -0.4)
 .. (2.2, -0.4) .. (2.4, 0.4) .. (0, 2) .. (1, 0);

 \end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then I added in the green link as a circle:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots, hobby, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  knot diagram/every strand/.append style={
    ultra thick,
    red
  }}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
 \begin{knot}[scale=2,
   consider self intersections=true,%ignore endpoint
   % intersections=false,
   end tolerance=0.05mm,
  draft mode=crossings,
   flip crossing/.list={1,3},
   clip width=8,
   clip radius=8pt,
   only when rendering/.style={
   }
   ]
 \strand ([closed]2,0) .. (3, 0) .. (4, 2) .. (1.5, 0) .. (1.8, -0.4)
 .. (2.2, -0.4) .. (2.4, 0.4) .. (0, 2) .. (1, 0);
\strand[green] (2, -0.5) circle[radius=2cm];
 \end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I see:
[image]

The crossing numbers have changed of course, but that's not a problem -- I can flip them. The problem is the crossing marked as '2': it's in the wrong place.
If I try and flip it, the situation gets worse (zoom from image):

[image]

*I eventually succeeded in drawing this knot by using a second Hobby curve for the green strand(*).* I have drawn my knot -- I'm not looking for further advice on how to do this particular example. But I'm keen to get a better grasp on the `knots` library and I'd like to understand **why the attempt using a circle behaves that way** -- does anyone know? I tried making my circle bigger and smaller and shifting it a bit left and right, all to no avail... I don't know if there's something in the knots options that I was missing? Other than where the start point of a circle might lie, it's essentially symmetric with the crossing marked 7, which is handled correctly... so perhaps there's something to do with the circle starts?

(*) The working code, for completeness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots, hobby, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  knot diagram/every strand/.append style={
    ultra thick,
    red
  }}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
 \begin{knot}[scale=2,
   consider self intersections=true,%ignore endpoint
   % intersections=false,
   end tolerance=0.05mm,
  draft mode=crossings,
   flip crossing/.list={1,4, 5,6 },
   clip width=8,
   clip radius=8pt,
   only when rendering/.style={
   }
   ]
 \strand ([closed]2,0) .. (3, 0) .. (4, 2) .. (1.5, 0) .. (1.8, -0.4)
 .. (2.2, -0.4) .. (2.4, 0.4) .. (0, 2) .. (1, 0);
\strand[green] ([closed]2, -1) .. (3.5, 0) .. (2, 1) .. (0.5, 0);

 \end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer, but is an explanation of the problem.*

When `consider self intersections` is set to `true` then each path is split into segments so that the intersection routine can be used to find its self intersections.  When doing so, it removes empty segments which consist of just `moveto`s.  It would appear that there is a bug when doing this with a circle, since a circle starts with a `moveto` from the centre to a point on the circumference.  By removing the various clips, it is possible to see the path that the knots library is using to find the self intersections:

[image: the circle with the moveto removed]

So when the `moveto` is removed, it's the wrong `moveto`.  This is a bug.  I've opened an issue on github: https://github.com/loopspace/spath3/issues/29

Comment: thanks, that's really interesting! Especially as there are many existing knots using circles that don't run into this issue...

Comment: @MairAW It's the combination of circles with `consider self intersections=true` that triggers it, and I think that most uses of circles with `knots` are actually links so they don't look at self intersections.

Comment: @MairAW A smidgeon of progress: I think `consider self intersections=no splits` does *not* trigger the bug.

Comment: @MairAW I think I've fixed it, https://github.com/loopspace/spath3/commit/2bf1293426a6a852a6c8506b6175dac2ab4ee634, if you have the time to test then that would be great.

Comment: i downloaded spath3_code.dtx from the github there and ran pdflatex on it, hit enter to ignore it grumbling about checksum, reran my code above and indeed crossing 2 is now in the right place!