# TikZ knots issue: circular "paper-cutout"s at intersections when using double

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

I'm trying to draw a trinity/trefoil knot with accompanying linking circles with the knots package, but I'm encountering a "paper circular-cutout" issue at intersections as demonstrated in the image below. (The faint circular "[crop circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188447)" artifacts are not the issue, being only visible on the .jpg conversion from .pdf.)

Decreasing the value of `double distance` reduces, but does not eliminate the issue.

A manual drawing of the linked ring using arcs outside of the `knot` environment is feasible, but the well-known issue with `double`'s PDF rendering artifacts (manifesting here as lines at points where two `double`s join) destroys the whole beauty of the thing: most viewers will see things electronically, not on paper.

Is there a workaround to this issue?  I'm hoping for one that doesn't require a lot of manual intervention after adjusting the parameters in the code below: I intend to put math and text flowing along the various portions of the links and inside of the knot, the right parameters will need to be adjusted on the fly.

[image: Trinity Paper-cutout]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}% 

\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Ring Parameters
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RingRadius}{3};

    % Trefoil parameters
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\TrefoilAngle}{120};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\InnRadius}{1};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\OutRadius}{4};

    % Coordinates for trefoil bounding circle
    \coordinate (bottom) at (270:\OutRadius);
    \coordinate (left) at (150:\OutRadius);
    \coordinate (right) at (30:\OutRadius);

    % Coordinates for trefoil "hole"
    \coordinate (innBot) at (270:\InnRadius);
    \coordinate (innLeft) at (150:\InnRadius);
    \coordinate (innRight) at (30:\InnRadius);

    \begin{knot}[%
        % Use no splits to prevent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708135
        consider self intersections = no splits,
        end tolerance=0.5pt,
        line width = 2,
        line join=round,
        clip width=1,
        ignore endpoint intersections=true,
        % draft mode = crossings,
        flip crossing/.list={2, 3, 8, 6},
        ]

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %  Trefoil  %
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \strand[%
            only when rendering/.style={%
            draw=teal,
            double=teal!20,
            double distance=9pt,
            },
        ]
        (innBot)
        to [out = 180, in = -30 - 0.5*\TrefoilAngle]
        (left)
        to [out = -30 + 0.5*\TrefoilAngle, in = 120]
        (innRight)
        to [out = -60, in = 90 - 0.5*\TrefoilAngle]
        (bottom)
        to [out = 90 + 0.5*\TrefoilAngle, in = -120]
        (innLeft)
        to [out = 60, in = -150 - 0.5*\TrefoilAngle]
        (right)
        to [in = 0, out = -150 + 0.5*\TrefoilAngle]
        (innBot)
        ;

        %%%%%%%%%%
        %  Ring  %
        %%%%%%%%%%
        \strand[
            only when rendering/.style={%
            draw=red,
            line width = 2pt,
            double=red!20,
            double distance=9pt,
            },
        ]
        (0, 0) circle [radius = \RingRadius];
    \end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need to increase the size of the circles used to create the over/under effect. It's one of `clip radius` or `clip width` but I can never remember which!

Comment: That was it! `clip radius = 16pt` does the job in this instance. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, what a record time response! I've always wanted to thank you for all of the tikz libraries you've created and maintain. Really fantastic stuff that has saved me (and I'm sure many others) a ton of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `clip radius` to something sensible. For testing, you can try: `clip width=2, background color=yellow`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RingRadius}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TrefoilAngle}{120}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\InnRadius}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\OutRadius}{4}
\coordinate (bottom) at (270:\OutRadius);
\coordinate (left) at (150:\OutRadius);
\coordinate (right) at (30:\OutRadius);
\coordinate (innBot) at (270:\InnRadius);
\coordinate (innLeft) at (150:\InnRadius);
\coordinate (innRight) at (30:\InnRadius);
\begin{knot}[
consider self intersections=no splits,
end tolerance=0.5pt,
flip crossing/.list={1,2,5,6,8},
clip width=1,
clip radius=20pt,
]
\strand[
teal, double=teal!20,
line width=2pt, double distance=9pt,
] (innBot)
to [out=180, in=-30 - 0.5*\TrefoilAngle] (left)
to [out=-30 + 0.5*\TrefoilAngle, in=120] (innRight)
to [out=-60, in=90 - 0.5*\TrefoilAngle] (bottom)
to [out=90 + 0.5*\TrefoilAngle, in=-120] (innLeft)
to [out=60, in=-150 - 0.5*\TrefoilAngle] (right)
to [in=0, out=-150 + 0.5*\TrefoilAngle] (innBot);
\strand[
red, double=red!20,
line width=2pt, double distance=9pt,
] (0,0) circle [radius=\RingRadius];
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Trefoil with interlaced ring]

Do not use `;` after `pgfmathsetmacro`. You do not need `only when rendering`.